# VBA Combining Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to combine row values if that row has merged rows.

This is the original

[image: [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Yst.png)]

And this is expected.

[image: Expected Result]

Thanks

This is the script that I'm working on at the moment. But I need to find a way to determined if the row has merged cell, Then the other columns will combine into 1 cell.

```vb
Sub TestCopy()

Dim Src As Range
Set Src = Range("A1:A2")
   
Dim Dst As Range
Set Dst = Range("A5")

Dim DstRow As Range
Set DstRow = Range("A5:A6")
    
Dim myArray() As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim c As Range

ReDim myArray(Src.Rows.Count - 1)
intCount = 0
For Each c In Src
myArray(intCount) = c.Value
intCount = intCount + 1
'MsgBox Join(myArray, vbCrLf)
Next c

Dst = Join(myArray, vbCrLf)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. No one can copy/paste it when it's an image.

Comment: Please update your screenshot to include row and column headings, otherwise it's no way to know what's the cells' reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeCell()
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, sTxt As String
    Dim dataRng As Range, aRng As Range
    Set dataRng = Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' Loop through column B
    For Each c In dataRng
        sTxt = ""
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            ' Locate merged cell
            If c.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                ' Get the related range in column A
                Set aRng = c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(c.MergeArea.Cells.Count)
                ' Cocat text
                For Each d In aRng.Cells
                    If Len(d.Value) > 0 Then
                        sTxt = sTxt & Chr(10) & d.Value
                    End If
                Next
                ' Merge cell and update its value
                aRng.Merge
                aRng.Value = Mid(sTxt, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image]